# Modify a cookie in JMeter to include curly braces around the value

Tags: cookies, jmeter

I have the following JSR223 PostProcessor where the captured c_QUID value is to be surrounded by curly braces and used in a cookie. For example if c_QUID is 5575-9878-4848-8897, then I need to set the cookie as {5575-9878-4848-8897}. What can I modify in the below script to do that? As of now it does not add the curly braces.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.*

//Get cookie manager
CookieManager cm = sampler.getCookieManager()
log.info("XXXXXXXXXX QUID " + vars.get("c_QUID"));
Cookie c = new Cookie("QUID", vars.get("c_QUID"), "stage.randomtesting.com", "/", true, 1557578515)
cm.add(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation the value:

```
new Cookie("QUID", "{" + vars.get("c_QUID") + "}",
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be something like:

```
Cookie c = new Cookie("QUID", "{" + vars.get("c_QUID") + "}", "stage.randomtesting.com", "/", true, 1557578515)
```

By the way, you might want to use current timestamp as the cookie expiration date because your value of `1557578515` is in the past so the application [might not accept it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires), you might want to replace it with something in the future? See [Creating and Testing Dates in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-and-testing-dates-in-jmeter-learn-how) - Learn How article for more details

Also wouldn't that be easier just to define the custom cookie in the [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)?

[image]